# How can I handle duplicate inputs name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dynamic form which probably has duplicate input names.

```js
$(".add_more_staff").on("click", function(){
  var $newMember = $(this).siblings('.company_members').clone();
  $newMember.insertBefore($(this));
})
```

```css
a, input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="company_members">
      <input  class="staff_name"  type="text" name="name" required placeholder="name" />
      <input  class="staff_mobile"  type="text" name="mobile" required placeholder="mobile" />
      <hr />
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="add_more_staff" value="Add more staff" />
  <input type="submit" value="register_company_staffs" />
</form>
```

In the code above, you will have two inputs named `mobile` *(or `name`)* if you click on `Add more staff` button once.

Now I want to know, how should I get it in the PHP codes? According to some tests, `$_POST['mobile']` contains the last input value. So how can I get all inputs value in PHP?

- Should I make different names for new inputs in jQuery like `name="mobile-n"` *(`n = 1, 2 ..`)*
- Should I use array-name for inputs like `name="mobile[]"` ?
- Or what?

Comment: If you want to get all input values as array, do your second option `name="mobile[]"`

Comment: get in array, name="mobile[]", name="username[]", you will get all the values in array

Comment: As people mentioned, arrays would probably be your go-to.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  <div class="company_members">
      <input class="staff_name" type="text" name="name[]" required placeholder="name" />
      <input class="staff_mobile" type="text" name="mobile[]" required placeholder="mobile" />
  </div>
```

in PHP:

```
$staff_names = $_POST['name'];
$staff_mobiles = $_POST['mobile'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery, during appending the html, you can add dynamic increment variable to like

> staff_name_1, staff_name_2, staff_mobile_1, staff_mobile_2

with this, you can easily save or define the unique names, like I am showing you on simple example:

```
var a=0;
$(".add_more_staff").on("click", function(){
   $(".company_members").each(function(){
      a++;
      $(".staff_name").attr('name', $(".staff_name").attr('name')+a);

    });
});
```

Hope you can my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below it will contains data in groups, so you can easily loop it after post data and your JQuery code seems fine.

```
      <div class="company_members">
          <input class="staff_name" type="text" name="data[0][name]" required placeholder="name" />
          <input class="staff_mobile" type="text" name="data[0][mobile]" required placeholder="mobile" />
      </div>

      <div class="company_members">
          <input class="staff_name" type="text" name="data[1][name]" required placeholder="name" />
          <input class="staff_mobile" type="text" name="data[1][mobile]" required placeholder="mobile" />
      </div>
```